# How can I get these bootstrap links converted to haml?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Having trouble converting these links into haml....have tried

```
 %link {:rel => "stylesheet" href => "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous"}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? Please be more specific and clear so others can provide an appropriate answer

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
%link{rel: "stylesheet", href: "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css", integrity: "sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r", crossorigin: "anonymous"}
```

Btw, please check [this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes) out

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", integrity: "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7", crossorigin: "anonymous" %>
```

... is the correct [Rails way](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) (I'll delete if you'd prefer HAML only)

Comment: Would you like me to delete the response?